# Filtering on activerecord relation without additional sql query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I filter the results of a AR query without executing an additional query?

e.g.

```
u = User.where(name: "bob", age: [10, 20])
# 1st select query to db
u.class # ActiveRecord::Relation
tens = u.where(age: 10)
# 2nd select query to db
```

I don't want the second query to call the db, but rather filter on the results retrieved in u (1st query).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `ActiveRecord:Relation` only queries the db when its elements are accessed. So the sequence you have will not call the db at all unless you write something like `u.first` or `tens.first`.

It is a bit different in Rails console as each statement results are printed to console so it executes the query each time. You can skip the printing by appending `; 1` after each statement.

That aside, if you still want to filter the results with first query:

```
u = User.where(name: "bob", age: [10, 20]) # no query at this point
u.class # ActiveRecord::Relation
u.first # query to db
u.class # Array

tens = u.select{|x| x.age == 10} # no query to db
```

Comment: The console calls `inspect` on the returned object and prints this out. The method `inspect` for `ActiveRecord::Relation` calls `to_a` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-inspect which loads and returns the records http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-to_a, thus already performing the required queries.

Comment: Also, I use `; nil` instead of appending `; p 1`. Just `; 1` would actually already be sufficient.

Comment: @kristinalim true and better

Comment: But if you update data I doesn't work:
u = User.where(name: "bob", age: [10, 20])  # 1st select query to db
u.each{|u| u.firstname='something'} # only memory
tens = u.where(age: 10) && --> Second access to db without consider las update (firstname='something')
-->Tested not in console